# Discarding const qualifier

Tags: c++, class, operator-keyword

Why isn't discarding const qualifier allowed? Suppose we wrote:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    void operator=(const A&){ std::cout << "A&" << std::endl; }
    void operator=(const A&&){ std::cout << "A&&" << std::endl; }
};

const A a;
A b;

int main()
{
    a = b; //Error: discarding qualifier
}
```

Couldn't someone provide a reference where the Standard disallows that?

Comment: Why should it be allowed? So that you can mutate things that are `const`? That would make `const` quite pointless.

Comment: @juanchopanza So why is the following http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f094f8dad70b4c5f perfectly valid?

Comment: Exactly as juanchopanza said. Why use `const` at all in this case in particular? That seems like asking why you might get an error passing an `int` to a function that expects an `std::string`.

Comment: @St.Antario what do you think is wrong with your example?

Comment: @St.Antario Because `A::foo()` is `const`.

Comment: No, no. I understood the things. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f2c3c7de2b1873a

Comment: A `const` member function can be called on `const` and non-`const` instances, because it promises not to modify anything. A non-`const` member function can only be called on non-`const` instances, because it does not promise not to modify the instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem there is that `a` is `const` and therefore `operator=`, which is supposed to modify the object on which is called, is disallowed. This is caused by `const`-correctness.

Declaring `operator=` to be `const` would not make sense, because the semantic of `operator=` are that it should modify the object on which it's called with the right hand side value and return a `T&` reference to the left hand side object, which is not possible if the left hand side object is `const` (excluding `const_cast` usage).

On the other hand, the following is allowed:

```
int main()
{
    A b;
    const A a = b;
}
```

because in that case it's *construction* of a new constant object.

---

As you said, the standard specifies this at §9.3.2/3 with the following wording:

> A cv-qualified member function can be called on an object-expression (5.2.5) only if the object-expression is as cv-qualified or less-cv-qualified than the member function.

Comment: I was looking for only this line of text. __A cv-qualified member function can be called on an object-expression (5.2.5) only if the object-expression is
as cv-qualified or less-cv-qualified than the member function.__ Wasn't that hard to just provide that?

Comment: I mean, you could add it to the answer.

Comment: @St.Antario Sure I can add that to the answer.